# Entityframework throws Error when Mapping Entity to Base AND Inherited Class

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, mapping

I get an Error when I try to map an Entity to a Property of a Baseclass AND to another Property of a derived Class.

Example:
[image: Inheritence]

The Error is: Error 1   Running transformation: A member named Car cannot be defined in class MyModel.Racer. It is defined in ancestor class MyModel.Person.

Is there a mistake in my DB-Model?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem here is the Navigationproperties. I just had to rename the "Car"-Propertie in the Baseclass to "FavouriteCar" and in the derived class "Car" to RaceCar. Works Nice!

Answer (score 1):

The FavouriteCarID should not appear on the inheriting type's entity - it should only be mapped to a property on the base type.

Try to **remove FavouriteCarID** from person or **RaceCarID** from Racer..

Because CarID is already **mapped with person** .so we cannot refer that again in Racer table...

Its like u r trying to create a duplicate class for person...so it leads to error dude...

I hope u can correct the issue... *Remove the mapping between* **Car** and **Racer** tables. It will work

Comment: I thought about that, but from DB-Design-Aspect I think: 1. A Person doesn't have a RaceCar 2. RaceCar and Favourite are two different things. What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: Remove the mapping between Car and racer tables

Comment: But a Racer is a Person. Sorry, but I think it's not that easy. I know how to fix the Error Message but that doesn't fix Problem. thx anyway

Comment: dude.. Separate person in one table and refer with faouritecar and also Racer.. Then only it will work for all cases

Answer (score 0):

Please find the table structure.... Hope u r looking for this. This way u can create Db structure know??

```
public class car 
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
}


public class Person 
{
    public int personid { get; set; }

     // List<Favourite> .. we can do by querying dude only.

}

public class FavouriteCarList : Person, car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }//pk
    public int personid { get; set; }//FK
    public int FavoriteCarID { get; set; }//FK from Car
}


public class Racer : car,person 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }//pk
    public int personid { get; set; } //Fk
    public int RaceCarID { get; set; }//FK from Car

}
```

Comment: For FavouriteCar, Do you try to inherit from Person AND Car? In c# it is not possible. Also you could Map multiple Favourite Cars to one Person, that is not what I want

Comment: Dude thats the db design that u have to create.. Yes u can map multiple FavouriteCar to the person table using that design.. Check FavouriteCarList table

Comment: I understand your requirement. While creating person u need to add multiple Favoritecar isn't it? .That will be done by this manner only... Check my design once again..